# How can I start a new Process and wait until it finishes?

Tags: c#, process.start

I want to start a program with C# (could use `Process.Start()`). Then my program should wait until the started program is closed, before it continues.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After you call `Start()` add: [`Process.WaitForExit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx)

```
 var myProcess = new Process {StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(processPath)};
 myProcess.Start().WaitForExit();
```

Comment: You can't pass any arguments to the constructor like you can with the static Start method, however you can supply them using the StartInfo property, e.g.

    var p = new Process
        {
      StartInfo =
       {
        FileName = @"cmd.exe",
        Arguments = ...
        UseShellExecute = false
       },
      };
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Close();

Answer (score 4):

There are two mechanism. You can either hook the Process.Exited event or what you probably really want is to call Process.WaitForExit().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx